# Chromecast Receiver Polling or Daemon

Tags: video-streaming, chromecast, google-cast

I have a need to perform some sort of routine polling or session communication (to another backend service) when a user is streaming through their chromecast.   Typically I could do this from the client but given that the client could be off or locked (e.g. phone lock screen) I will probably need to shift this logic elsewhere.  I have a custom receiver built but not really sure the best way to implement a solution.   I am evaluating a couple options but wonder if anyone has tried this before:

1. Custom Receiver daemon - Thinking of some sort of daemon alert the backend of any streams that are still live.   The big challenge that I have is knowing how to write a daemon in the custom receiver or find all he active streams.
2. Completely separate server that will poll the custom application for each active session and get a status.   I worry that the chromecast reciever will not allow me to have two separate web sockets (or request the status of one from a separate server).

Thanks in advance